# UITableView - Sliding content inside each cell horizontally

Tags: ios, uitableview

**This is my first native iOS app...**

Exactly like the iTunes app on iOS does, by having a tableview that you can scroll vertically, and then each row, you can scroll independently horizontally. At least this is ow I imagine it to work.

how would I implement this? I imagine a view inside each tableCell that can scroll horizontally?

Can any one please shed some light on this and what I might read or try to do

Comment: Those does not do what I asked. They scroll the whole table, I dont want to do that

Comment: As I understood, you want to use a scroll view that will be scrolled vertically, and in it you will have to put another scroll view that will have a horisontal scroll. Or in your case Scroll View inside the cells

Comment: As zenith answered, use custom UITableViewCell which contains UIScrollView in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the scroll view into the cells content view and then just the content size property of the scroll view to whatever length you want. Here I have set the width of scroll view to 1000 and the height to 44 (which is the default size of the UITableViewCell).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIScrollView *vwScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    vwScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
    vwScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 44);

    [cell.contentView addSubview:vwScroll];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I just need to set my height of the cell I think, but it seems to work

Answer (score 2):

The only option I can think of is if you place a `UIScrollView` inside the `UITableViewCell's` view.

Note though, that this may cause problems in regard to the vertical scrolling behavior of the UITableView itself.

Comment: Lets say Im putting images inside the scrollView, will they be offscreen, and when I scroll to the side they will slide into view?

Comment: Sure thing, when you find out just let us know if it is working how you wish! hoping it does

Comment: Read this http://snipplr.com/view/51211/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643986/horizontal-table-view-within-tableviewcell-not-responsive-to-scrolling

Comment: thanks for the links! reading them now, ill let you know If i can get this going

Answer (score 1):

To achieve independently scrolling rows similar to the **App Store** app on iOS, one approach is to nest a **Collection View** inside a **Table View Cell**.

I wrote a [Swift tutorial](http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/) with step-by-step instructions on the setup, including how to wire the **Collection View** **dataSource** to the **Table View Cell**.

The tutorial includes a [working sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/HorizontalScrollingCollectionView) and a link to an [Objective-C tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the free Sensible TableView framework provides these cells out of the box. Should give you a good head start since you're still starting out. Hope this helps.